# How do I shift the frequency of a track by x Hz?

Tags: frequency, adobe-audition, pitch-shifting

I have been meditating using binaural beats for some time. I was wondering if the effects could be achieved by using an audio track instead of a static noise.

My idea was to take a song, convert it to mono, have 2 instances of the song playing on left and right individually while the other songs frequency is shifted by 5.5Hz across the entire track.

With binaural beats, you have 2 static noise playing which frequencies are different by 5.5Hz. This makes the brain "virtually" perceive it as 5.5Hz, which is the frequency that is said to help reach a certain state of trance.

Now, how do I shift the frequency of a track by 5.5Hz across the entire track so I have 2 versions of the song I want with 5.5Hz difference?

I prefer using Adobe Audition as I have subscribed to Adobe Creative Cloud. I looked into the `Pitch Shifter...` but the units displayed are not in Hz which I don't quite understand.

**Update**:

After reading all of the replies I realised that I lack some basic knowledge about the matter. I went on to read more about this topic and learned that this would be impossible to achieve without distortions. Thanks to everyone who were kind enough to explain it to me in great detail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because.

Comment: Just a quick note - shifting by 5.5 Hz is unlikely to do what you want. I know I couldn't listen to sound as you describe...

Comment: I'm going to leave open - it's a simple question at it's core about pitch-shifting a track, but it also has some good quality answers to the larger question now.

Answer (score 2):

[Binaural Beats](https://www.binauralbeatsmeditation.com/the-science/) is a psychoacoustic phenomenon that occurs between 2 frequencies as perceived in a binaural space. To contrast - in a piece of music, you are listening to not only infinite number of frequencies, but those frequencies are inconsistent and change with song structure.

To create binaural beats in a song, every frequency will require a new tuning, and furthermore, every song will require relatively unique tunings to achieve the same beat frequencies. Therefore, it's my hypothesis that it's only possible once you structure each and every frequency in a precise manner, **by adding *x* hz** to that frequency value. *x* would represent the desired 'difference' frequency. Because each frequency in music has various amplitudes and durations, it could be difficult to create a program that can execute this.

I'll break down the [beat phenomenon](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/beat.html) below:

E.g. 1. Given 1 frequency:
 - The wave cycle of a sine wave with a frequency of 75hz will oscillate at 75 times per second. 
 - In the same time frame, a 70hz sine wave will oscillate at 70 times per second. 
 - Therefore, the difference in these two frequencies is 5hz. When the two waves are superimposed, they will create a 'beat' phenomenon at the difference frequency of 5hz.
 - The ratio of 75/70 is about 1.0714, which is about an increase of 1 semitone and 19 Cents [according to this calculator.](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-centsratio.htm)

E.g. 2. Now, given two frequencies 70hz and 100hz (sine waves) heard at the same time:

- If you include as little as 1 or more frequencies (or sine waves) in a sound, the difference between them are subsequent ratios. I.e. the respective ratio is 70:100 or 0.7.
- To create a 5hz difference between these 2 frequencies, we will find 2 different ratios; to create 'beating'. With 70hz & 100hz on one sound, and 70hz (+5hz) & 100hz (+5hz) on the other sound, the Ratio will equal 75/70 (1.0714 for 70hz) and 105/100 (1.05 for 100hz).
- In other words, the two frequencies require two different tunings or Pitch-shifts. This is simply because they *are* different frequencies.

Typically, when you Pitch shift a song or a sound, all the frequencies will move up or downward by a single Ratio. That results in different frequency gaps, as Mark and Rory have answered here already.

- Transposing a 60 second song by 12 semitones gives a ratio of 2:1, which means the frequencies will double; 60hz tone will now equal 120hz. A 70hz tone will now be 140hz.
- If it is a Pitch-Time algorithm, the resulting song length will be 30 seconds (twice as fast), and the song will be out of sync in a stereo space (with left or right shifted).
- Even with a ratio of 1.0714, which is just over 1 semitone, the audio track will still fall out of sync dramatically:

[image]

In another experiment, I've attempted binaural beats using a Synth bass sound, which only contained a few frequencies. It is probably easier to achieve, focusing only on the bass and sub-bass frequencies in the music, especially if you can break them down into a few frequencies. So it may be helpful to filter the song (<80hz) and then focus on the lowest bass frequencies.

From my limited knowledge, the binaural beats would occur only when those bass sounds are heard, which further limits how practical it is with instrumental sounds. In conclusion though, I would recommend researching binaural beats to learn how much more it can be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe Audition Pitch Shifter, Pitch Bender or Stretch and Pitch effects will not let you shift all notes in your audio track by 5.5Hz. Instead, it allows you to shift in tonal increments, such as semi-tones, cents or by ratio. What this means is that different frequencies will be shifted by different amounts.

As an example using a Ratio of 2 would shift up a 440Hz A by 440Hz, but would shift an 880Hz A by 880Hz. It doubles the frequency, which is the same as going up an octave.

I'm not sure if there are any commercially available sound effects that will let you do this easily - it's not the sort of thing you typically want for audio. That said, I would imagine you could build one using a ring modulator circuit, and feeding it with a 5.5Hz tone to generate sum and difference frequencies

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what you are actually asking for a moment, you might realise that it is not possible to do what you are asking.

Sure, you can take a pure sine wave and shift the frequency of that sine wave by a number of hertz, and you will get another sine wave, but music is made up of sounds of many different frequencies.

For example, at 5Hz (below the threshold of hearing), a shift of 5Hz would push a sine wave up one octave in pitch, but at 10Hz, a shift of 5Hz would push that same sine wave up only half-an-octave in pitch. Consequently a 20Hz sine wave would only see a pitch rise of a 1/4 octave.... and so on.

What you are proposing, if it were possible, would have to be done by dissembling the entire spectrum into pure sine waves of an infinitely small bandwidth and then re-assembling them into a coherent waveform again.

Sorry, but your question makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

I realise that you were hoping for solution in Adobe Audition, however there is a solution in Logic Pro X that might work.

In Logic Pro X you can change the overall pitch by using the Varispeed feature:

[Logic Pro X: Use Varispeed to alter the speed and pitch of audio](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13094?locale=en_GB)

However you can only change pitch when you're changing the speed at the same time, but you can change the speed only if required.

Therefore, you could change the pitch and speed of one track, then change the speed ONLY of the other track. They'd both end up at the same faster speed, with one as a slightly different pitch.

You can display the pitch difference whilst changing the first track by 5.5Hz, then note the speed difference to adjust the other track by accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Logic Pro X also does not let you change all the tones by 5.5Hz - there is no commercial product which does this.

Answer (score -1):

AudioSculpt, from IRCAM will do what you want. It has a high-end vocoder that it uses to split the audio into thousands of discrete bands, actually, into it's full sinusoidal array, and then you can just pick and choose which one you want and where to put them.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically possible. The way to do this is to convert the audio into multiple fix frequency sounds (by Fourier transform). And shift these sounds individually.

Comment: However, the result might not be what you want, Kappa

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with the Waves Sound Shifter II.
It allows you to choose the frequency

Comment: Waves Sound Shifter does not actually do what the OP wants - it works the same way as the Audition one, and almost all others. You can only alter Pitch Ratio or Time Ratio, so shifting each note by a fixed no of Hz is not possible.